# Proof of open mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

In the proof of the open mapping theorem in my book it states that for $f$ holomorphic and nonconstant in a region $\Omega$ we can find $\delta$ such that the disc $|z - z_0| \leq \delta$ is contained in $\Omega$ and $f(z) \neq f(z_0)$ on the circle $|z - z_0| = \delta.$ My question is how can we pick such a disc? I get that it is nonconstant but I don't see how that guarantees us a disk with the mentioned properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't such a circle, there is a sequence $z_1,z_2,\ldots$
converging to $z_0$, with $z_k\ne z_0$ and $f(z_k)=f(z_0)$. By the
identity theorem, then $f$ is constant in a neighbourhood of $z_0$.

Comment: But can't it be constant in the neighborhood and still be nonconstant in the region $\Omega?$

Comment: A holomorphic function constant on a disc within a connected open set is constant.